# How to Merge two array with different key but same value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have two objects which I am trying to merge with different key The first object I need to compare with Id and my second object I need to compare with Option.

And My final expected output  i have mentioned below

Apologize my bad formatting . I'm literally new to this forum. Please help.

Thanks in Advance.

My First Object

```json
[
  {
    Category__c: "Option",
    Description__c: "Exdoor",
    Id: "a0F1e000000EgcGEAS",
    Name: "with door"
  },
  {
    Category__c: "Upgrade",
    Description__c: "Exdoor",
    Id: "a0F1e000000EgcHEAS",
    Name: "Upgrade"
  },
  {
    Category__c: "New Option",
    Description__c: "1300 wide with doors",
    Id: "a0F1e000000EgcIEAS",
    Name: "doors"
  },
  {
    Category__c: "Oven",
    Description:"1450 Door",
    Id: "a0F1e000000EgcJEAS",
    Name: "Oven Option: Wall Oven"
  }
]
```

My second Object

```json
[
  {
    Option: "a0F1e000000EgcJEAS",
    Price: 0
  }
]
```

Now My expected output is

```json
[
  {
    Category__c: "Option",
    Description__c: "Exdoor",
    Id: "a0F1e000000EgcGEAS",
    Name: "with door"
  },
  {
    Category__c: "Upgrade",
    Description__c: "Exdoor",
    Id: "a0F1e000000EgcHEAS",
    Name: "Upgrade"
  },
  {
    Category__c: "New Option",
    Description__c: "1300 wide with doors",
    Id: "a0F1e000000EgcIEAS",
    Name: "doors"
  },
  {
    Category__c: "Oven",
    Description:"1450 Door",
    Id: "a0F1e000000EgcJEAS",
    Price: 0,
    Name: "Oven Option: Wall Oven"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array.prototype.forEach() which executes a provided function once for each array element.

In the forEach we will check if the current data.id equals to the selected option. if so, we will use the dot notation to add it's price to the data.

Edited : i updated the code to grey 123 request and changed selected to be array and for his request

```js
const data = [
{
Category__c: "Option",
Description__c: "Exdoor",
Id: "a0F1e000000EgcGEAS",
Name: "with door"

},
{
 Category__c: "Upgrade",
Description__c: "Exdoor",
Id: "a0F1e000000EgcHEAS",
Name: "Upgrade"

},
{
Category__c: "New Option",
Description__c: "1300 wide with doors",
Id: "a0F1e000000EgcIEAS",
Name: "doors"
},
{
Category__c: "Oven",
Description:"1450 Door",
Id: "a0F1e000000EgcJEAS",
Name: "Oven Option: Wall Oven"
}];

const options = [{
     Option: "a0F1e000000EgcJEAS",
     Price: 0
}];

data.forEach(x => {
  const selected = options.find(y => y.Option === x.Id);
  if (selected){
  x.Price = selected.Price;
  }
})

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Ran Turner
I don't have a field called Price in my data list how to add the price field in the Data list

Comment: using the dot notation. look at the code above

Comment: selection is also an array not single object Ran Turner

Comment: I updated my answer and changed selected to array (assumed the chosen selected object is at index 0..

Comment: @RanTurner I didn't copy your answer mate, I've proposed a new way of solving the problem. I've seen your answer and `upvoted` it to make it useful. But recent changes that you've made are not what OP wants. The array may contain more than one object. So it's not the right solution.You need to find the object in the `selected` array then add `Price` 

Comment: I updated the answer according to grey 123 changes.

Comment: @grey123 please look at the updated answer

Comment: @decpk its the same code resides the map but what ever makes you feel right..

Comment: That's what OP wants... @RanTurner ☺

Answer (score 1):

It would be better not to mutate the original object instead make changes in new object.

```js
const data = [
  {
    Category__c: "Option",
    Description__c: "Exdoor",
    Id: "a0F1e000000EgcGEAS",
    Name: "with door",
  },
  {
    Category__c: "Upgrade",
    Description__c: "Exdoor",
    Id: "a0F1e000000EgcHEAS",
    Name: "Upgrade",
  },
  {
    Category__c: "New Option",
    Description__c: "1300 wide with doors",
    Id: "a0F1e000000EgcIEAS",
    Name: "doors",
  },
  {
    Category__c: "Oven",
    Description: "1450 Door",
    Id: "a0F1e000000EgcJEAS",
    Name: "Oven Option: Wall Oven",
  },
];

const selected = [
  {
    Option: "a0F1e000000EgcJEAS",
    Price: 0,
  },
];

const result = data.map((obj) => {
  const searchObj = selected.find(({ Option, Price }) => Option === obj.Id);
  if (searchObj) return { ...obj, Price: searchObj.Price };
  return obj;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: decpk const Selected is also an array not a single object

Comment: okk let me change my answer

Comment: You just copied my answer and changed to map..

Comment: please show me sir how to do I'm literally new sir Ran Turner

Comment: i meant @decpk..

Comment: const selected =[ {
  Option: "a0F1e000000EgcJEAS",
  Price: 0,
},

    Option: "a0F1e000000EgcIEAS",
    Price: 20,
  }]

Comment: @grey123 Is this what you want

Comment: Yes sir @decpk thanks a lot for quick response.

Comment: @Ran Turner Thanks a lot.Praise the Lord

Comment: @grey123 Then accept one of the answers

Answer (score 1):

```
Below will do
```

```js
let one = [{
        Category__c: "Option",
        Description__c: "Exdoor",
        Id: "a0F1e000000EgcGEAS",
        Name: "with door",

    },

    {
        Category__c: "Upgrade",
        Description__c: "Exdoor",
        Id: "a0F1e000000EgcHEAS",
        Name: "Upgrade",

    },

    {
        Category__c: "New Option",
        Description__c: "1300 wide with doors",
        Id: "a0F1e000000EgcIEAS",
        Name: "doors",

    },
    {
        Category__c: "Oven",
        Description: "1450 Door",
        Id: "a0F1e000000EgcJEAS",
        Name: "Oven Option: Wall Oven"
    }
]

let two = [{
    Option: "a0F1e000000EgcJEAS",
    Price: 0,
}]

function merge(one, two, oneKey, twoKey) {
  var byMap = {}
  two.forEach((el)=> {
    byMap[el[twoKey]] = el;
  });
  one.forEach((el)=> {
    Object.assign(el, byMap[el[oneKey]] || {});
  });
}
merge(one, two, "Id", "Option")
console.log(one)
```